# something went wrong "error CS1513: } expected"

Tags: c#

I am a beginner coder
I wrote a program but it can not be compiled, there is an error message:

> error CS1513: } expected

I am using visual studio code
please help me to find the issue in the following lines of code

```
using System;
namespace My_Program
{
    internal class NewBaseType
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to roll 1 or 2 dice");
            int dice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // 1 dice
            if (dice == 1) {
                 Random numberGen = new Random();

            numberGen.Next(0, 6);
            int roll = 0;
            int attempts = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the die");
            Console.ReadLine();

            while (roll != 6) {
            roll = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("Your rolled: " + roll);
            attempts++;

            Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attempts + " attempts to get a six");
            }
            }

            //2 dice
            if (dice == 2) {
                     Random numberGen01 = new Random();
                     Random numberGen02 = new Random();

             numberGen01.Next(0, 6);
             numberGen02.Next(0, 6);
            
            int roll01 = 0;
            int attempts01 = 0;

            int roll02 = 0;
            int attempts02 = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the die");
            Console.ReadLine();

            while (roll01 != 6) {
            roll01 = numberGen01.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("Your rolled: " + roll01);
            attempts01++;

            while (roll02 != 6) {
            roll02 = numberGen02.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("Your rolled: " + roll02);
            attempts02++;

            int total = roll01 + roll02;

            Console.WriteLine("It took you " + total + " attempts to get a two sixes");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

the error is on the very last line (line 66) could anyone help me?

Comment: If you indent your code in the right way (or let your editor do it) then the braces are much easier to pair up.

Comment: Indeed, you need to use a cleaner and better code formatting standard, regardless of the war about where to put the open brace... Stack Overflow is not intended to ask where is a missing or redundant brace, sorry. That said, a simple copy/paste in my VS shows that 2 closing braces are missing at the end of the code provided. That's all, just add `}}`.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to what IDE/tools you're using here; most tools will *actively fight you* trying to indent (or not, as the case may be) like this. However, in devenv (Visual Studio): press "Ctrl+E, D" - hey presto, your code is formatted correctly and the error is obvious. It *could* be as simple as adding `} }` at the end (appropriately formatted, obviously), but I can't presume where the braces are *actually* meant to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using visual studio; pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> will re-format your document to the configured conventions, which should make the fundamental problem obvious - the braces are indeed unbalanced:

[image]

It looks like you are missing 2 `}` braces, to end the `class` and the `namespace` scopes. However, it could also be that there are oddities in the code logic itself, re braces.

Note: the reformat option is also available via the menus - Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document:

[image]